# SSRS 2008 R2 with SQL Server 2008 (non R2) ReportServer databases

Tags: sql-server-2008, ssrs-2008

We are moving to a scale out deployment of SSRS 2008 Enterprise with reporting services running on 2 front ends connecting to the "ReportServer" and "ReportServerTempDB" databases on a separate SQL Server 2008 cluster.

Can you run Reporting Services 2008 R2 while connected to the report server databases that live on a SQL Server 2008 (non R2) database server?

Thanks,
Dan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes.

Both SQL Server 2008 R2 and SDQL Server 2008 SSRS can run on a SQL Server 2005 or higher back end.

[From MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms157285.aspx)

> For SQL Server 2008 R2, there have been no changes to the content that is listed in this topic.
>
> ...
>
> SQL Server 2005 or SQL Server 2008 can
> be used to host the databases. Do not
> use SQL Server 2000 or earlier
> versions of SQL Server.